# Python, Pandas, remove n-letters of string without removing index/title

Tags: python, pandas

this is probably a easy fix that just eludes me right now.
I have a excel file with the following content.

[image]

from it I want to filter out the "Num-" from the rest. For simplicitys sake I use `.str` here.

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(r'C:\...\test.xlsx')
df_test = df_test.filter(like='Order_Number', axis=1)
df_test = df_test['Order_Number'].str[4:]
df_test.head()
```

The output comes out without the title `Order_Number` though and I am not sure why. How can I preserve it without adding it manually back?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are assigning the new values of `'Order_Number'` column to entire dataframe, instead of assigning them to the actual column. Try:

```
df_test['Order_Number'] = df_test['Order_Number'].str[4:]
```